# Menelaus' Theorem

Tags: geometry

Let G on the median AA' of $\triangle ABC$ such that $\frac{AG}{GA'} = 2$. A line passing through G intersects sides AB at P and AC at Q. Show that $\frac{PB}{PA} + \frac{QC}{QA} = 1$. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let R be the point where that line intersect the side BC and without loss of generality suppose R is nearer to B than C. Then, by Menelaus' theorem on ABC we have
 $$\frac{RB}{RC}\frac{QC}{QA}\frac{PA}{PB}=1$$ 
and by Menelaus' theorem on A'AB $$\frac{RB}{RA'}\frac{A'G}{GA}\frac{PA}{PB}=1$$
Or samely
$$\frac{PA}{PB}=2\frac{RA'}{RB}$$
Substituting on the first equation
$$\frac{QC}{QA}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{RC}{RA'}$$
Summing up that and the inverse of one before we have 
$$\frac{PB}{PA}+\frac{QC}{QA}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{RB+RC}{RA'}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{RB+2BA'+RB}{RB+BA'}=1$$

Comment: oh wow i did not think of constructing an extension...thank you !

Comment: @erica No problem;) I think of it because it was the only way to use Menelaus' theorem.

Comment: i have another menelaus problem that i posted. i got halfway through it and i am stuck at the point i am at. do you think you could take a look at it ?

Comment: Would you mind addressing a link in order to be sure which problem is

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2186879/menelaus-theorem-2/2186940#2186940